# Hibernate throws - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a basic task to remove a cascading mission but I get an exception.

the class `Missions` has a `OneToMany` relationship with the class `ResponsesCheckLists` and `OneToMany` with the class `StatistisquesMissions`.

I have the following entities:

**Missions.java**

```
@Entity
public class Missions implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="idMission")
private long idMission;

@Column(name="nomMission")
private String nomMission;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="Respmission", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection <ResponsesCheckLists> ResponsesCheckLists;
//getters and setters

 @JsonIgnore
public Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> getResponsesCheckLists() {
    return ResponsesCheckLists;
}

public void setResponsesCheckLists(Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> responsesCheckLists) {
    ResponsesCheckLists = responsesCheckLists;
   }
}
```

**ResponsesCheckLists.java**

```
@Entity
public class ResponsesCheckLists implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idResponsesCHeck")
    private long idResponsesCHeck;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="missionsId")
    private Missions Respmission;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="checkLists_Id")
    private CheckLists CheckLts;
     //getters and setters

     public Missions getRespmission() {
        return Respmission;
    }

    public void setRespmission(Missions respmission) {
        Respmission = respmission;
    }

    public CheckLists getCheckLts() {
        return CheckLts;
    }

    public void setCheckLts(CheckLists checkLts) {
        CheckLts = checkLts;
    }

}
```

**StatistisquesMessions.java**

```
@Entity
public class StatistisquesMessions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idStat")
    private long idStat;

    //@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="equipement_ids")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Equipements statEquipements;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="statMission_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Missions statMissions;
}
```

When I want to delete `Missions` from the MySQL database as follows (API REST):

```
@Override
    public Boolean DeleteT(Pk id) {

        T tt= GR.findOne(id);
        GR.delete(tt);
        return true;
    }
@Autowired
    private MissionsMetier missionM;

@RequestMapping(value="/DeleteMissions")
    public Missions DeleteMissions(@Param(value ="idMission") long idMission){
        Missions mis = missionM.getT(idMission);     //I have the object "Missions"
        return missionM.DeleteT(idMission);
        }
```

then I get the following error

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`BDTasks`.`responses_check_lists`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK73o6po4goa6ulera1d6md58i6` FOREIGN KEY (`missions_id`) REFERENCES
>   `missions` (`id_mission`))

The hibernate query:

```
Hibernate: select stat0_.stat_mission_id as stat_mis8_9_0_, stat0_.id_stat as id_stat1_9_0_, stat0_.id_stat as id_stat1_9_1_, stat0_.nbre_conforme as nbre_con2_9_1_, stat0_.nbre_not_conforme as nbre_not3_9_1_, stat0_.res_conforme as res_conf4_9_1_, stat0_.res_not_conforme as res_not_5_9_1_, stat0_.equipement_ids as equipeme7_9_1_, stat0_.stat_mission_id as stat_mis8_9_1_, stat0_.total_check_lists as total_ch6_9_1_, equipement1_.id_equipements as id_equip1_3_2_, equipement1_.actifs_id as actifs_i5_3_2_, equipement1_.date_ajout_eq as date_ajo2_3_2_, equipement1_.date_modification_eq as date_mod3_3_2_, equipement1_.nom_eq as nom_eq4_3_2_, actifs2_.id_actif as id_actif1_0_3_, actifs2_.date_ajout_actif as date_ajo2_0_3_, actifs2_.nom_actif as nom_acti3_0_3_ from statistisques_messions stat0_ left outer join equipements equipement1_ on stat0_.equipement_ids=equipement1_.id_equipements left outer join actifs actifs2_ on equipement1_.actifs_id=actifs2_.id_actif where stat0_.stat_mission_id=?
Hibernate: delete from statistisques_messions where id_stat=?
Hibernate: delete from missions where id_mission=?
```

---

**Edit1:**

```
@Autowired
    private MissionsMetier missionM;

    @RequestMapping(value="/DeleteMissions")
    public Missions DeleteMissions(@Param(value ="idMission") long idMission){
        Missions mis = missionM.getT(idMission);     //I have the object "Missions"
          // delete ResponsesCheckLists
    Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> Rp = res.FinsRespoCHeckListsMission(idMission);
    for(ResponsesCheckLists r : Rp){
        System.out.println("***** id response "+r.getIdResponsesCHeck());
         res.DeleteT(r.getIdResponsesCHeck());
     }

     //delete StatistisquesMessions
     Collection<StatistisquesMessions> st =mis.getStat(); 
     for(StatistisquesMessions stat : st){
              statis.DeleteT(stat.getIdStat());
          }

    mis.removeMissionsFromUsers();
   // return  missionM.DeleteT(idMission);
    //return true;
    return missionM.DeleteT(idMission); 

   return  missionM.DeleteT(idMission);

        }
```

**I have the same problem**

---

**Edit2:**

```
@Autowired
    private MissionsMetier missionM;

    @RequestMapping(value="/DeleteMissions")
    public Missions DeleteMissions(@Param(value ="idMission") long idMission){
        Missions mis = missionM.getT(idMission);     //I have the object "Missions"

        // delete ResponsesCheckLists
    Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> Rp = res.FinsRespoCHeckListsMission(idMission);
    for(ResponsesCheckLists r : Rp){
        System.out.println("***** id response "+r.getIdResponsesCHeck());
         res.DeleteT(r.getIdResponsesCHeck());
     }

     //delete StatistisquesMessions
     Collection<StatistisquesMessions> st =mis.getStat(); 
     for(StatistisquesMessions stat : st){
              statis.DeleteT(stat.getIdStat());
          }

    mis.removeMissionsFromUsers();

       return  missionM.DeleteT(mis.getIdMission());
        }
```

How can I delete `Missions` its `ResponsesCheckLists` and its `StatistisquesMessions` children?

thank you very much,

Comment: You must delete the children before delete the parent. Find the `ResponsesCheckLists` 's key in the `Missions` then delete the `ResponsesCheckLists`, then do the same with `StatistisquesMessions`. After that you can delete your `Missions` without error.

Comment: I have the same problem, thank you to consult the last update @TuyenNguyen

Comment: I think that your code still wrong. What does the `mis.removeMissionsFromUsers();` do? why you have to call it before delete the `ResponsesCheckLists` and `StatistisquesMessions`?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen this function `mis.removeMissionsFromUsers()` Allows emptying the list of users assigned to the Mission without deleting the users.                                        `@PreRemove
  public void removeMissionsFromUsers() {
      for (Users u : employees) {
          u.getMissions().remove(this);
      }
  }`

Comment: Did you try to debug? And at which line is the point cause error?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen The problem comes from these lines: `GR.delete(tt);` And `return missionM.DeleteT(mis.getIdMission ());`

Comment: Update your mappings to this `@OneToMany(mappedBy="Respmission", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> ResponsesCheckLists;`

Comment: I have the same problem. I did not understand why? @AbdullahKhan

Comment: Did `orpahnRemovel` help?

Comment: I did as you @AbdullahKhan : said:`@OneToMany(mappedBy="Respmission",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval=true)  ` But I have the same problem; ` Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (BDTasks.responses_check_lists, CONSTRAINT FK73o6po4goa6ulera1d6md58i6` FOREIGN KEY (missions_id) REFERENCES missions (id_mission))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved through the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DeleteMissions")
    public Missions DeleteMissions(@Param(value ="idMission") long idMission){
        Missions mis = missionM.getT(idMission);     //I have the object "Missions"

        // delete ResponsesCheckLists
        Collection<ResponsesCheckLists> Rp = res.FinsRespoCHeckListsMission(idMission);
        for(ResponsesCheckLists r : Rp){
                r.getCheckLts().setResponsesChecks(null);
                r.setCheckLts(null);
               res.saveT(r);
               res.DeleteT(r.getIdResponsesCHeck());
         }

         //delete StatistisquesMessions
         Collection<StatistisquesMessions> st =mis.getStat(); 
         for(StatistisquesMessions stat : st){
                  statis.DeleteT(stat.getIdStat());
        }   

       return  missionM.DeleteT(idMission);
        }
```